# Find Value by position on plain HTML in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, nokogiri

My Html file is not having any classes . I am trying to get the no. from the plain Html

```
<html>
 <head></head>
  <body>
     PO Number : [4587958]   
  </body>
</html>
```

I am able to find out the PO Number test by using

```
require 'rubygems'

require 'nokogiri'   

PAGE_URL = "a.html"

page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(PAGE_URL))

data = page.css("body").text
puts data 
test = data
ponumber = test.scan('PO Number')
puts ponumber
```

I am not able to get the no.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get the number by scaning with a regexp that matches numbers:

```
page.css('body').text.scan(/\d+/)
# ["4587958"]

page.css('body').text.scan(/\d+/).first.to_i
# 4587958
```

`scan` returns an array with all matches. If you have multiple numbers in your document, just choose the element you want to pick:

```
# Example:
#   Invoice Number : [78945824] PO Number : [4587958]

page.css('body').text.scan(/\d+/)
# ["78945824", "4587958"]

page.css('body').text.scan(/\d+/)[1].to_i
# 4587958
```

Comment: Thanks spickermann.. It work's .. Just wanted to know if i wanted to retrive second value. like Invoice Number : [78945824] PO Number : [4587958]